# Drawbacks on having validations on Entity object spring/JPA/Java

Tags: java, jpa, orm, entity

As far as I know there is a principle to not create class instances with inappropriate fields values. 
To handle the problem I use class constructors with all necessary fields. Then I check arguments and throw exceptions if parameters are wrong.

Is it appropriate to use this solution in JPA Entity classes or I should check it in service layer?

Parameters are validated on controller layer and before saving with Hibernate annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = ColumnNames.NAME, nullable = true)
  @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "{person.name.size}")
  String name;

  @Column(name = ColumnNames.DATE_OF_BIRTH, nullable = true)
  private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

  protected Person(){}

  public Person(String name, LocalDate dateOfBirth)  
     throws IllegalArgumentException, NullPointerException { 

     Objects.requireNonNull(name);
     Objects.requireNonNull(dateOfBirth);
     Preconditions.checkArgument(name.length() > 1, 
        "Name should have length more than 1 character");

     this.name = name;
     this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }

  //getters
}
```

Comment: It is always advised to handle data validations on the controller side. A typical enterprise system will do data validations on the controller layer, business logic and implementation on the service layer and actual changes on the repository layer

Comment: @Coder Thank a lot for your answer! I validate data on the controller layer and before saving due to Hibernate annotations. Is it a bad practice to use entity constructor validations? I suppose it prevents from 'wrong' class instances.

Comment: did you get what you are looking for or do you have any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

First let's get clear on the three main components in a typical `MVC` architecture.

***Controller***: The controller component works as a gateway between your input and the business logic. This is where you specify what kind of API you are looking to develop, is it a `GET` request or `POST` request? What kind of data should it accept? What should your API return as a response. This layer is also used to validate the data that's coming from the user so that we don't do all the heavy lifting in service layer and then later conclude we don't have appropriate data to begin with. After we conclude the sanity of the data, we then move on to the actually logic implementation area ***Service***.

***Service***: The service should provide the API with business logic, therefore being an abstraction to your repository, the services should be the only ones with access to the repositories. This is where all the heavy lifting is done and if deemed necessary we then resolve to ***Repository*** layer to access the database.

***Repository***: This is the closest layer to the database and it is simply present to handle the all the communication between application and database.

Coming to your case, where you wanted to do validations on the entity itself, there are certain downsides to it.

- Security: If you are putting validations on the entity itself, you are typically exposing it in the controller level which is considered a big security issue as you are typically exposing your table structure, hence making the application vulnerable.
- Heavy weight: All the other layers which are supposed to take care of this issue will simply act as a pass through, which increases load on your entities doing all the job.
- Maintenance: You might come across different specifications of these depending on the API itself. Then you are left with no option other than to rewrite an entire new entity with newer validations which lowers your re usability.

Feel free to reach out if I am unclear

.